# I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a IBM lenovo thinkpad r51 (non pae cpu) How do I install 13.04 from live dvd

Tags: system-installation

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a IBM Lenovo Thinkpad R51. It has a non PAE CPU. I Purchased a 13.04 Live DVD. The live dvd will not boot. Is it possible to work around this without jumping through a lot of hoops?

Comment: Can you tell us what happens (if anything at all) when you try to boot off of the disk?  

Do you get any kind of preliminary loading information, or is it just a blank screen, do you load into your original OS, etc.?

Comment: pae error message

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 13.04 needs PAE. There is a potential workaround at [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2113826)

Answer (score -1):

I used a Linux Live USB with 14.10

Booting with the option "forcepae" allowed boot from USB. Subsequent install seems to be working fine thus far although I am using lubuntu and looking for all performance tweaks as this is a much older laptop.

Comment: The question is about 13.04 though…